# Why does PHP header(charset) work while HTML <meta charset> doesn't?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

this one may be easy, but seems a problem for my server (or me myself).

I have this piece of code in `index.php`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');

// Some code for generating data to be displayed
foreach ($ObjectArray as $SingleObject) {
        print_r($SingleObject->getAllProperties());
    }
```

And it does this:

[image: Expected result, achievable with header()]

But I don't want to use `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"');` - I'd rather include HTML code from my `header.htm`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Cards</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
```

with my `index.php` like that:

```
<?php
include 'view/header.htm';
echo '<body>';
// Some code for generating data to be displayed
foreach ($ObjectArray as $SingleObject) {
        print_r($SingleObject->getAllProperties());
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
}
```

Unfortunately, this ain't too good. Charset still is recognized as UTF-8, but the result is far from my expectations:

[image: Unexpected result, when normal HTML is used]

Please tell me, what is happening and how to handle this kind of problem. Is it a case of combining HTML and PHP (clean PHP does use some fancy styling when HTML ain't present?) or maybe some mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: HTML and PHP headers are different - both should be set to UTF-8 (or whatever, as long as they are the same), as should your entire pipeline of code. Otherwise, you might get broken characters displayed on your page.

Comment: @Qirel the unfunny part is, when I set up the PHP header before applying HTML code, the HTML code does appear as plain text output, not HTML code...

EDIT: Okay, I changed `text/plain` to `text/html` in header() function, but still it does look awfully bad without line-dividing that was working before header.htm was added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatted look is preserved, because in the first case you have the content-type `text/plain`, while in the second case it is HTML (`text/html`).
You can wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags to preserve formatting when returning HTML.

```
<?php

include 'view/header.php';
echo '<body>';
echo '<pre>';
// ...
// your foreach here
// ...
echo '</pre>';
echo '</body>';
```

Comment: Okay, giving it a try. That's it. Thank you :) I also changed `text/plain` to `text/html` and kept both headers (PHP one and HTML one). I hope it is correct way to do it :)

Comment: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#answer) says it is OK.